# PyQt5 QSlider is off by one depending on which direction the slider is moved

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qslider

I'm having a problem with the QSlider element in PyQt5. Below is a simplified version of my code that only calls the slider. I have two methods: One to print the slider value when it is moving, and one to print the slider value once the user releases the button.

If you drag the slider to a position (let's say 10) and hold it there, it should print out 10. If you release it, it will print out 11 (if you dragged from the left-hand side) or it will print out 9 (if you dragged from the right-hand side.

I'm really at a loss for why it is off by 1 depending on which direction the slider is moved. I would like the two methods to print off the same number.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class GUIWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 0, 900, 900)

        # Slider
        self.eventSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.eventSlider.setFixedWidth(600)
        self.eventSlider.setSingleStep(1)
        self.eventSlider.setValue(0)
        self.eventSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.eventSlider.setMaximum(20)
        self.eventSlider.setTickInterval(1)
        self.eventSlider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.eventSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.slider_changing)
        self.eventSlider.sliderReleased.connect(self.slider_changed)

        GUILayout = QGridLayout()
        GUILayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        GUILayout.addWidget(self.eventSlider, 0, 0, 1, 9, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(GUILayout)

    def slider_changing(self):
        print(self.eventSlider.value())

    def slider_changed(self):
        print(self.eventSlider.value())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUIWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Apparently using valueChanged() rather than sliderMoved() will provide the values I want. Not sure exactly what sliderMoved() is measuring, then...

Comment: mmm, I understand that this behavior is strange for you but have a doubt: What is your specific question?

Comment: My question was how to get the same value when the user is dragging the slider as when the user has stopped dragging the slider. Looks like I can simply use valueChanged() for both behaviors, rather than trying to use sliderMoved().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by the mechanism of QAbstractSlider (which is the base class for widgets like QSlider).

Let's see the explanation in the documentation.

[`QAbstractSlider.sliderMoved(value)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderMoved):

> This signal is emitted when sliderDown is true and the slider moves. This usually happens when the user is dragging the slider. The value is the new slider position.

[`QAbstractSlider.valueChanged(value)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged)

> This signal is emitted when the slider value **has changed**, with the new slider value as argument.

The difference is that the `sliderMoved` signal is emitted when the slider is moved, **not** when the value is changed.
In fact, if you disable the [`tracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#tracking-prop), you'll see that the `slider_changing` will always print the **same** *current* value, until the slider is released.

That's what happens when tracking is disabled (the default):

- the slider is at 0
- you press the mouse on the handle
- `sliderPressed` is emitted, at this point the value and the position are still the same, 0
- you move the handle by one step
- `sliderMoved` signal is emitted, now the slider *position* is at 1, but the value is still at 0
- the slider is painted at the new position
- the slider "realizes" that tracking is disabled, so *now* it updates the *current* value
- the [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) signal is emitted

Since you're checking the `currentValue` within the `sliderMoved` signal connection, at that point the value has not been updated.

To get the actual value when the slider is moved you've two options:

- use [`sliderPosition()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderPosition-prop) instead of `currentValue` (or, better, get the parameter of `sliderMoved`, which already contains the new position (and possible new value, no matter if tracking is enabled or not);
- connect to `valueChanged()`;